# Is it possible to alternate rowspans?

Tags: html

I guess this schema of what i am trying to do will be more descriptive than the question itself.

```
+------------------------+-----------------------+
|                        |                       |
+                        +-----------------------+
|                        |                       |
+------------------------+                       +
|                        |                       |
+                        +-----------------------+
|                        |                       |
+------------------------+-----------------------+
|                        |                       |
+------------------------+-----------------------+
```

As you can see, i am trying to create a 2 column table where at some point it should be able to rowspan one of the columns, and eventually the other over the next 2 rows.

Am i missing some obvious way of doing it, or some advanced table tag/attribute? Or there is just no way of doing that using tables?

I am aware that it is possible to achieve that using other ways, but tables are what i am interested in, and what is the question about.

For reference:
There are some things i've tried and didn't succeed
http://jsfiddle.net/dbtYk/

Comment: Heh, interesting question, never thought about this in 12 years of HTML! I *think* this is impossible, but let me experiment a bit... Either way, this may be easier to do with normal block-level elements though.

Comment: 12 years of HTML ? o_O You need to refresh you knowledge. Using attributes 'rowspan' and 'colspan' you can create any kind of tables, even some very creative ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless I've missed something, [here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/dbtYk/2/) based on your jsfiddle

```
<table>
    <tr style="height:20px;">
        <td rowspan="2">left</td>   
        <td>right</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:20px;">
        <td rowspan="2">right</td>   
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:20px;">
        <td rowspan="2">left</td>   
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:20px;">
        <td>right</td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>left</td>   
        <td>right</td>   
    </tr>
</table>
```

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by Cicada the above unfortunately doesn't work in Chrome.

**UPDATE 2**

As pointed out by Alohci, adding a height makes it work in Chrome.  The above has been amended to reflect that, along with a [new jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbtYk/50/).

Comment: Unless I've missed something, your solution does not work (Chrome 19).

Comment: @Cicada - I'm starting to hate Chrome in the same way I hate IE... why can't any of these browsers work the same way!!  Thanks for pointing the issue

Comment: +1 Yes, it works when you give the rows a height. Add that to your answer and it's good.

Comment: @Alohci and Cicada - many thanks for your comments, answer updated... although I'm not sure how useful the exact height definitions will be in the real world (despite the jsfiddle now working on FF, IE and Chrome)

Comment: I guess height was the missing ingredient. My bad for putting too much trust in chrome and not testing extensively on other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Of course that is possible :-)

```
<table border="yes">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Just skip the cells that are already covered by spanned cells from a previous row.